Can custom document properties in a Word doc be mapped to content controls?
Is there a way to map custom document properties of a Word document to content controls? For example, if I add a custom property in the Backstage (under Info - Properties - Advanced Properties - Custom) named "MyProperty" with a Value of "Test" (as shown in the attached screenshot), I'd like to map that custom property to a plain text content control that I can insert in multiple locations of the document such that the content controls will all automatically update when the value of the custom property is changed.
Custom Document Properties
I have reviewed the information on Greg Maxey and GMayor's websites and tried their associated tools but have not figured out a way to do what I'm attempting.
I've reviewed information from Microsoft and other websites regarding how to map content controls. I've tried using the VBA expression "SetMapping(XPath, PrefixMapping, Source)" but I don't know what the XPath, PrefixMapping, and Source values should be for this expression. I know this information needs to come from the custom.xml file that is in the docProps folder when I change the doc file to a zip. The custom.xml file has the following content:
custom.xml file contents

You may want to look at: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/EnhancedDocProp_AddIn.html.

Is there a particular reason why you need/want to use Custom Properties? (There are of course many possible reasons, but e.g. you have to work with existing field codes, have to work with other software that uses them, want to allow the user to use a built-in dialog box to maintain their values are among several I've come across).

@jonsson it's because users will use the built-in dialog to maintain the values and I'm trying to find a solution to auto-update the values in content controls used in the document (including some CC's in the header) without macros.

There really just isn't a macro/VBA-free solution to that problem. If you only need updates to travel in one direction (i.e. the user changes the value of a property in the Custom Document Properties dialog, and you want to propagate that new value to other places in the document, then you either have to have a macro that updates the value of an element/attribute in a Custom XML Part and uses Word's content control mechanism to propagate the value, or you have to use { DOCPROPERTY } fields, and you have a macro to update them, or the user updates them. (cf.  the answer by @user27589787 )

...and of course updating the values of all { DOCPROPERTY } fields in all parts (story ranges) of a document is also non-trivial and will probably need code.
If you need updates to travel in both directions, e.g. a user types a value in a content control in the document and you need that value to be reflected in a Custom Document Property, that also requires code.
Further, AFAIK only Windows and Mac desktop versions of Word even let you update Custom Document Properties.

If you do not need Word Custom Document Properties then, using the same XML Parts that SharePoint generates, you can still edit "simple" property types in the Document Info (on what used to be called BackStage), on the Windows version of Word. I knew it was possible, but not what problems you might encounter, e.g. loss of data if your document travels via a SharePoint library. I was going to write it up here, then found https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/help-with-xml-schema-restrictions-contenttypes/29264e1d-279e-422e-b807-0666eaa01f1d which gives the gist.

No, you cannot map a content control to a traditional Word Custom Document Property, I.e. the kind of property whose name/value is stored in custom.xml.
You can only map to some built-in document properties, and elements/attributes in Custom XML Parts. That means that you cannot use Content Controls to propagate a change in the value of a Custom Document Property automatically in the same way that Word will propagate a change to, say, the built-in Title property (I.e. without VBA).
FWIW, you can demonstrate that you can't map a Custom Property in the same way that you can map a built-in property (i.e. one of the core or extended properties. Let's say I have a Custom Property called mycustprop , type text. Then if I look at the custom.xml, I will see something like this (your fmtid will probably differ and you will need to insert the value on your system to make this work):
<Properties xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties" xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
  <property fmtid='{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}' pid='2' name='mycustprop'>
    <vt:lpwstr>mycustpropval</vt:lpwstr>
  </property>
</Properties> 

If you had a single plain text content control in your document, you would be able to map to the <vt:lpwstr> element using, e.g., this:
Sub mapcc()
Dim cc As ContentControl
With ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1)
  .XMLMapping.SetMapping "/nsa:Properties/nsa:property[@name='mycustprop']/nsb:lpwstr[1]", "xmlns:nsa='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties' xmlns:nsb='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes'"
End With
End Sub

But it doesn't work. You can verify that this would be the correct mapping code for a regular Custom XML Part by inserting a Custom XML Part with the same XML, e.g.
Sub addcxp()
Dim x As String
x = "<Properties xmlns='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties' xmlns:vt='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes'>"
x = x & "  <property fmtid='{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}' pid='2' name='mycustprop'>"
x = x & "    <vt:lpwstr>mycustpropval</vt:lpwstr>"
x = x & "  </property>"
x = x & "</Properties>"
ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.Add x
End Sub

and then running the mapcc() Sub.
Technically, I don't really see why Microsoft could not have allowed mapping to Custom Document Properties. But they didn't. There is one likely technical obstacle, which is that these properties were originally implemented using a well-known set of structures in the COM/OLE Structured Storage format, which was the format used for Word .doc files before the .docx format. It's possible that allowing mapping as well might have created difficulties for existing software. For users with SharePoint, the new facilities associated with metadata in SharePoint document libraries were arguably an improvement.

I don't think there's an event to bind to for document property updates, but you could set a value when the document is opened, or add a control refresh the value. If you had a custom property "Foo", and a text content control "Bar", then
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Dim docControl As ContentControl

    ' I believe this has to be done by index
    For Each docControl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        If docControl.Title = "Foo" Then
            docControl.Range.Text = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Bar").Value
        End If
    Next docControl
End Sub


Just to expand on this a little. You've probably got a reason for wanting to use a content control, but just for clarity, you could also do this with a field (DocProperty). It wouldn't refresh automatically either, but it's more straightforward. Also, while document events exist that you could bind things to, the only way to use them is to turn off code security in Word, which doesn't feel like a strong plan.
